# unexpected package version getting uploaded to artifactory

Tags: python, artifactory, pypi, twine

I'm usint the following `twine` COMMAND TO UPLOAD A PACKAGE TO ARTIFACTORY:

```
twine upload --repository-url https://artifactory-url.com/ dist/* --user username --password password
```

It outputs this:

```
Uploading distributions to https://artifactory-url.com/
Uploading sdk-config-1.0.2.tar.gz
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 12.9k/12.9k [00:02<00:00, 5.42kB/s]
Uploading sdk-config-1.1.0.tar.gz
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 12.9k/12.9k [00:01<00:00, 8.68kB/s]
```

I only expected version 1.1.0 to be uploaded. I can't even see any sign of 1.0.2 Where would this be coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the packages in the `dist folder`. Removing 1.0.2 prevented it from getting uploaded.